# Selecting image in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm working in a chrome extension which just highlight the node that wrap the select area once I click on any region in browser.

It just outline a line around the selected element in DOM.

All work fine but with images with anchor tag.

How can I avoid when I click on an image with the a tag act the href?

Here I post my code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('scrapeTitle').onclick = function(event) {
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
            d = document;
            chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
                code: "document.addEventListener('mouseup', highlightSelectedBlock, false);function highlightSelectedBlock () {let elementWhereSelectionStart = window.getSelection().anchorNode;let closestBlockElement = elementWhereSelectionStart.parentNode; closestBlockElement.style.outline = '3px solid blue'; }"
            }, function(selection) {
                //console.info("text selected: ",selection);
            });

        });
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

[image]

Even using event.stopPropagation(); the  tag fires.

Comment: Try `event.preventDefault()` if `#scrapeTitle` is an `<a>` element or `event.stopPropagation()` if it is a `<img>`

Comment: @Titus, I have used them and stll happens the same. As you can see in the image.

Comment: That page seems to trigger a modal view showing the image. You would most likely have to override the eventListener on that element in your content script.

Comment: @holmberd As you say, such page does it and invoked via href tag via javascript but I need a general case solution.

Comment: I have to get to work, but see if you can override the onclick events on anchor and image tags, if present, then add your own.